# GST 10% flat on all item in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add 10% on cart and also include on shipping price.

Meance one item have 100$ and shipping price is 10$, then final price is:

> 100 + 10 = 110, then 110 *** 10%** = 121$ final price.

I know there are options for tax calculation, but not sure for shipping price include in tax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it from admin side Sales > Tax > Manage tax rules

You can add your own tax rule here. also this rules you can get from google.